# Angular2 ( 2.2.0) & Webpack 2 ( 2.1.0-beta.21) compile issue running build:prod

Tags: angular, webpack-2

Angular2 ( 2.0.1)  & Webpack 2 ( 2.1.0-beta.21) NO issue, I can perform nom run build:prod wo any problem...

When I upgrade Angular2 to the latest version (2.0.1),

npm run build  // => no error

but,

npm run build:prod //  => I get an error

```
Failed to exec build:prod script..
.... `del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p 
tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress   
--profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 
'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js'  
'!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 
'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'`
```

The only changes in my **package.json** are  :

```
....
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.0",
"@angular/core": "2.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.2.0",
"@angular/router": "3.2.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.2.0",
....

# not changed

"devDependencies": {
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
"@types/node": "^6.0.45",
"angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.2",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
"del-cli": "^0.2.0",
"html-loader": "^0.4.4",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"typescript": "^2.0.3",
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.21",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
```

}

**web pack.config.common.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'angular2-router-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        './src' // location of your src
    )
  ]
};
```

**web pack.config.prod.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge.smart(commonConfig, {
entry: {
    'app': './assets/app/main.aot.ts'
},

output: {
    path: './public/js/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/js/app/',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'angular2-router-loader?aot=true&genDir=public/js/app'
            ]
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: false
    })
   ]
});
```

**tsconfig.aot.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"outDir": "./public/js/app"
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"dist",
"assets/app/polyfills.ts"
],

"angularCompilerOptions": {
"skipMetadataEmit" : true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Issue was raised using the latest **@angular, @angular-compiler, and @angular/compiler-cli** (version 2.2.0) and web pack (version 2.1.0-beta.21)
*... I also tested with the latest versions 2.2.1 / 2.1.0.beta.27 ...*

in the production script, running

```
ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json
```

compilation output the **.ngFactory** in the directory specified in **tsconfig.aot.json**

```
( outDir: " ./public/js/app"
```

concatenated with the same directory structure as my project(  /assets/app/... , so the final path to be used by web pack will be

```
./public/js/app/assets/app/..
```

this path needs to be know by webpack loaders (genDir parameter ) ...  so in my 
**webpack.confid.prod.js** I need to declare it :

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'angular2-router-loader?aot=true&genDir=public/js/app/assets/app'
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```